# Could not uninstall software. (Android)

Tags: android, uninstallation

Why is my created program uninstallable? Please help? I have no idea how to move on.. This is a terrible bug in the sense that lay people will tag this as a spam, virus etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set this app as device administrator, remove it from Settings> Location and Security> Device admins. Then you can uninstall the app :)

Comment: Wow I remove the admin setting and I can now uninstall? What is the reason behind that purpose? I could not think of a thing why you can not uninstall a software with admin setting  enabled.

Comment: You might have set that app as your device administrator manually or that app might have set itself as a device admin. 

Usually & mostly Malicious apps does it (set itself as device admin without phone's owner perms) to steal info from the phone.

If any app is set as Device admin then that app cant be uninstalled until you remove it as a device admin.

You know what is the meaning if administrator or admin, so just think that the app was device admin, how could be a device admin uninstalled? :P :)